# RestTemplate authentication while setting userName and password

Tags: spring, rest, web-services, spring-mvc

I have a curl command but I want to pass this information with userName and password while calling the rest API, every thing I have tried doesn't work.

```
curl -u E-BOARD:HVRid992Xl740NnWOkjk -X GET --header 'Accept: application/json' 'https://XXXXXX.fr/AAAAAA/BBBBB/v1/details?abc=hsdfh&zyx=asdfsdf
```

My rest API looks something like this

```
String url = new StringBuilder(urlConfigService.getProfiles().getBaseUrl()).append(relativeUrl).toString();
    **String hiddenAccess = "ASHGHGHJ:HVRid992Xl740NnWOkjk";**

    // @formatter:off
    UriComponentsBuilder builder = UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl(url)
            .queryParam("refEboard", refEboard)
            .queryParam("idLangue", "FR");
    // @formatter:on

    HttpHeaders requestHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    requestHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    requestHeaders.add("Authorization", hiddenAccess);
    HttpEntity<?> httpEntity = new HttpEntity<String>(requestHeaders);
    restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(0, new StringHttpMessageConverter(Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
    String result =
        restTemplate.exchange(builder.build().toUri(), HttpMethod.GET, httpEntity, String.class).getBody();
    return (T) new Gson().fromJson(result, type.getClass());
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you are trying to send basic authentication credentials. To do this you have to encode username and password in Base64 and set request header like this:

*Basic (username:password Base64 Encoded)*

This is how you do it:

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
HttpHeaders header = new HttpHeaders();
String auth = username + ":" + password;
byte [] authentication = auth.getBytes();
byte[] base64Authentication = Base64Utils.encode(authentication);
String baseCredential = new String(base64Authentication);
header.add(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, "Basic " + baseCredential);
             header.setAccept(Collections.singletonList(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN));

HttpEntity<String> request = new HttpEntity<String>(header);
restTemplate.exchange(builder.build().toUri(), HttpMethod.GET, request, String.class);
```